# Android - How to know if a view overlay another view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a RelativeLayout with two views inside. The view1 is recreated inside the layout in a random position every ten seconds. view2 is in a static position and is bigger then view1. I want to know when the first view is created inside the second view area, how can I do that?

I'm currently trying this code but id doesn't work well.

```
        if (paramsView1.topMargin > View2Ystart
            && paramsView1.topMargin < View2Yend
            && paramsView1.leftMargin > View2Xstart
            && paramsView1.leftMargin < View2Xend) {
        return true
    }
    else
        return false;
```

It returns true only if view1 is touching a side of view2. I want it returns true only if view1 is totally inside view2.

Comment: You can get the coordinates and the dimensions of each view and do the math to determine if there is overlap.

Comment: I'm currently trying to do that but without success. I added some code to my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `getLeft()`, `getRight()`, `getTop()`  and `getBottom()`.

```
if (v1.getTop() >= v2.getTop() &&
    v1.getLeft() >= v2.getLeft() &&
    v1.getRight() <= v2.getRight() &&
    v1.getBottom() <= v2.getBottom()) { ...
```

Be mindful that these values will be available when the parent is laid out, i.e. not immediately after `addView()`.

Another possible solution, which may be more flexible, is to build `Rect` instances with each view's coordinates, e.g.

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
Rect rect2 = new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());
```

Then you can use [`rect1.contains(rect2)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains%28android.graphics.Rect%29) or [`Rect.intersects(rect1, rect2)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect%29) or any other combination.

Comment: The above statement is only true if v1 is within v2, not if it overlaps, but the idea is there.

Comment: @zgc7009 The question specifies "I want it returns true only if view1 is _totally_ inside view2."

Comment: I think he added the last line in the edit, in that case this works fine.

Comment: I just tried your solution with Rect objects using .contains() method. It works great

Answer (score 0):

For me the suggested solution does not work. Instead I used this and it is OK:

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect((int)childTop.getX(), (int)childTop.getY(), (int)childTop.getX()+childTop.getWidth(), (int)childTop.getY()+childTop.getHeight());
Rect rect2 = new Rect((int)button.getX(), (int)button.getY(), (int)button.getX()+button.getWidth(), (int)button.getY()+button.getHeight());

if (rect1.contains(rect2)) {
      
} else {

}
```