# How to detect overlap and reset locations of textviews in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

So I have two TextViews in a RelativeLayout in my xml file. When they are localized to different languages, there will be a chance that the two views will overlap with each other.

In this case I want to put them into two lines instead of just one line. How to detect the overlap and reset their position so on is on top of the other in java code?

Comment: You can adjust your layout properly for the changes, can you post your layout xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to know if a view overlay another view in RelativeLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047644/android-how-to-know-if-a-view-overlay-another-view-in-relativelayout)

Comment: I have the same issue, want to eliminate(GONE) a view if they overlap, programmatically.  If I find the answer I will post it to this question. I suspect it might be in the ViewTreeObserver listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with a LinearLayout and by using the textview's auto wrap feature Iwas able to detect if the textview wrapped.  By using a ViewTreeObserver and looking at the number of lines for the textview I then programmatically set the view to Gone.

```
final TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
text.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
             new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
         int lineCount = text.getLineCount();
         Log.d(this, "LineCount = " + lineCount);
         if (lineCount > 1) {
             text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
         getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
     }
 });
```

Just have to make sure your layouts don't ellipsize or that you set the singleLine or Maxlines to true or 1.  I set Max line on the one textview I want gone to 2 so that it will wrap if it won't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your layout in a language spefic layout folder.

Your standard layout in `res/layout`

another in `res/layout-ar` (example for arabic)

Comment: i want to detect if two views are overlapped in java programmatically because idk which language will cause the overlap